# Is there a tool for checking CLS compliance?

Tags: .net, cls-compliant

Is there a tool that can analyse my .NET code (C# and [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)) and tell me *why* things are not CLS Compliant?

Visual Studio is happy to tell me a parameter is not CLS compliant, but it doesn't get me any closer to fixing the problem as I don't know the cause.

Example Visual Studio error:

> Parameter 'xyz' is not CLS-Compliant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say I know of a tool, and I tend to use the MSDN page *[Language Independence and Language-Independent Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx)* to check if the type of the parameter/variable is CLS compliant. See the section of the table named 'Types'.

There was also a fair bit of discussion about this some time ago in the blog post *[FxCop and CLS Compliance](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2003/07/21/10358.aspx)*.

Answer (score 1):

From memory it's not too hard to do.  I'm not aware of a tool, but this [page](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Making-Your-Code-CLS-Compliant/) here describes what you need to change.

The big ones are using type specific structs (think uint32 instead of uint) and using an "_" in your public members.

Answer (score 0):

Preemptive rebuttal: to my knowledge, FxCop does not support CLS compliance checks. Perhaps code analysis in VS does but I cannot check at work.

You could just google the warning message you get.